# How can I get a fresh start?

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-suspension, abuse, sock-puppets

On stackoverflow I asked questions which were apparently preposterous. I got somehow suspended when creating my recreating my account. I assume this somehow gives me a bad name. Is there any way to get a nice, fresh start again as if I did not ever visit before? Like possibly, I am more likely to get suspended again or for longer time if I already did. Is there any way to get a completely fresh start again? I just want a clean slate that's all.

Comment: Was it that your original account was suspended? You should wait it out, and after you come back, contribute positively. You'd be surprised how people are usually very forgiving. I can recall site moderators who were, before becoming such respected members to be elected for such positions, troublemakers who were suspended (for a long time).

Comment: " I got somehow suspended when creating my recreating my account." If your previous account was suspended then creating a new account to get around the suspension is against the rules.

Comment: "*I just want a clean slate that's all.*" If we gave a clean slate to everyone who wanted it, at any point in time, why bother having a metaphorical slate at all? If you're suspended, you're supposed to be *suspended*: prevented from using the site. If suspension is to matter, you shouldn't be able to duck out of it just by asking for the rules to not have to apply to you.

Comment: Your account can also be suspended automatically because you recreated an account that was previously deleted by moderators as “no longer welcome”. I see that there are a few more accounts around yours that have had some attention from moderators. In your case, I **strongly** advise you use the [Stack Overflow “contact us”](https://stackoverflow.com/company/contact) form, preferably with your *original account*, and honestly and openly ask the community managers how you can best regain access to SO. Further accounts are only going to make matters worse at this point.

Comment: Are you the same guy who made this other Meta post about getting suspended for "apparently preposterous" questions? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332869/why-does-my-question-get-deleted-when-i-delete-my-account

Answer (score 18):

> Is there any way to get a nice, fresh start again as if I did not ever visit before?

Yes. Wait out the rest of the suspension period -- use it, for example, to read plenty of other questions and answers and think carefully about what makes them good or bad --, and the slate will be as blank as you want it to be upon your return.

If you're under a suspension, attempts to get around that suspension before it ends will *not* be seen as anything other than bad-faith attempts to circumvent the site's moderation, and they won't do anything to help your account.